# Angular observable subscription can it be unsubscribed within an inner subscription?

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe

The following code has a timer and a get request within. If the request returns error, the timer should stop. Can you stop the timer within the inner subscription (i.e. the request)? Any potential memory leaks? Is it a good practice?

```
let sub = timer(500, 1000).subscribe(() => {
  this.http.get<any>(url).subscribe(result => {
    //...
  }, error => {
    //...
    sub.unsubscribe();  // can this be done here?
  });
});
```

Comment: Sure, you can unsubscribe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have makes it harder to cleanup/track everything since a subscription triggers another.

You can actually use `mergeMap` to get the same result (I would recommend `switchMap` or `concatMap` in case the request takes longer than your polling interval) but also let the error propagate to the top `Observable`:

```
let sub = timer(500, 1000).pipe(
  switchMap(_ => this.http.get(url))
).subscribe(result => {
  ...
}, error => {
    // sub is already unsubscribed at this point since there was an error
});
```

### To answer the question:

As for memory leaks, your original code should be fine if `let sub` is the same as `this.sub`.

Comment: Hey, nice one. I guess you have provided an alternative way to code it. But do you mind answering my original questions, which are about memory leaks, etc. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, yes, they are the same variable (edited). OK, thanks, since you go beyond the questions and provided other suggestions, I picked yours as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

- `Can you stop the timer within the inner subscription`

Yes you can.

- `Any potential memory leaks`

Nothing more than unsubscribing in your `ngOnDestroy`. Can't speak for the rest of your code, so I won't say "yes" or "no".

- `Is it a good practice`

It's neither good nor bad, it's simply code here. I don't think you have another solution, exdept for maybe a websocket to simplify the code, but that's all.

Comment: So I guess its safe to do so? Thank you.

Comment: @user1589188 depends on what you mean by safe, but if you mean memory-wise, then yes, it is !

Comment: @user1589188 altough I didn't see the inner subscription (I focused on your question), but for that, Andrei is totally right, use an operator instead of two subscribes.

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry although you answered first, I picked @Andrei as the answer for the bonus code he added.

Comment: @user1589188 totally fine by me ! See you around.